# Setting `Load User Profile` to false on DefaultAppPool via appcmd

Tags: iis, iis-7

Is there an appcmd for setting `Load User Profile` to false on `DefaultAppPool` on IIS7 via appcmd?

I have already tried this

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools /[name='DefaultAppPool'].processModel.loadUserProfile:false
```

But this only sets it for the defualt App Pool and doesnt change the main setting called "

```
Set Application pool defaults..."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the following:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:applicationPools "/[name='appPoolNameGoesHere'].processModel.loadUserProfile:false"

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:applicationPools "/[name='appPoolNameGoesHere'].processModel.loadUserProfile:true"
```