# Using X509Certificate2 to get PrivateKey causes CryptographicException "Invalid provider type specified"

Tags: private-key, cryptographicexception

everyone,

I am developing a web application that uses X509Certificate2 to get a private key from a certification file. Code snippet looks like following:

```
    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetSignProviderFromPfx()
    {
        var strFileName = "c:\cer\mycerfile.pfx";
        var strPassword = "000000";            
        X509Certificate2 pc = new X509Certificate2(strFileName, strPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        var ThePivateKey = pc.PrivateKey;

        return (RSACryptoServiceProvider)ThePivateKey;
    }
```

But the statement pc.Privatekey  causes a  System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException "Invalid provider type specified" . I'm sure the certification file has no problem, it really has a private key. And the property pc.HasPrivateKey is also return true.

The test environment is VS2013,  window 7.

I also tried following:

a. I debugged it in VS2013 with iis express, the problem occured.

b. I debugged it in another computer with same enviroment with mine, the problem occured too.

c. I published the application to a server with iis running on Windows Web Server 2008 R2,  it worked fine.

d. I published the application to widows azure website, it also worked fine.

Therefore, I guess the code snippet has no problem. The key reason raising the exception is that there may be some problem about running environment.  I checked and compared the reading/writing right on the certification file in different environment, all of them are same.

Anybody can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I have been having the same problem and this is what I did to solve it. Hopefully this will help you too.

We had to set Load User Profile to True in the app pools advanced settings

You can also set it in the web.config I believe.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity/

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem, but in a docker container, was able to put the command from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788848/setting-load-user-profile-to-false-on-defaultapppool-via-appcmd

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

may be it useful to you;
On local try:

```
X509Certificate2 pc = new X509Certificate2(strFileName, strPassword);
```